# How do I get the actual row object from a TreeView in Python

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have a `GtkTreeView` like this

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Name     + Age      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Adam     + 15       +
+ Jane     + 19       +
+ Arnold   + 23       +<
+ Russell  + 10       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

If I select Arnold then I know I've selected Arnold by doing the following

```
selection = self.viewFriends.get_selection()
model, tree_iter = selection.get_selected()
print model[tree_iter][0]
```

How do I get the actual object corresponding to Arnold's record in the model ?

The `GtkTreeIter` object which I receive on calling `get_selected()` is always a new object.

Comment: What do you mean with "object id of the selected row"? You mean the object id of the object that is represented/shown in that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the headers to being clickable and then tie their "clicked" event to a function/method that will take their row ID. Then this function can be used to set a data member to the changed id.